# How to deduce the triangle vertices in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

If I draw triangles using OpenGL, how do I deduce their vertices for each fragment? Sending the position from vertex shader interpolates it, leading to the loss of information.

Comment: You will need a geometry shader for that. But better think if this is really what you want before.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/164572). You clearly want these vertices for some purpose. That purpose is what you need to ask about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a geometry shader you may access all three vertices of your triangle, thus you may pass them to the fragment shader via in/out (aka varying) variables. To prevent them from interpolating, just use `flat` [interpolation qualifier](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers).